# CMake Error in installing opencv on rp4

Tags: pi-4, opencv

i use following guide to install opencv

[https//:learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-raspberry-pi/](https://learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-raspberry-pi/)

in step5 of guide installation have error

```
~/opencv/build $ make install
```

out put is

```
...
[ 99%] Built target example_tapi_squares
[ 99%] Built target example_tapi_clahe
[ 99%] Built target example_opengl_opengl
[100%] Built target example_opengl_opengl_interop
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RELEASE"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /installation/OpenCV-/share/licenses/opencv3.
  Maybe need administrative privileges.


make: *** [Makefile:74: install] Error 1
```

what caused this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you skipped the step where you set `cwd=$(pwd) # Save current working directory`. This results in the variable `cwd` being empty , so the installation prefix will be incorrect: `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$cwd/installation/OpenCV-"$cvVersion"`.

This means it'll try to install everything into `/installation` which is a folder directly at the root of your filesystem, a folder that you don't have write access to as a normal user.

I've never tried this particular guide, but I assume that if you follow each step carefully, you should be able to make it work.